# How to create synchronous call in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have code something like below

```
function main() {
casper.start();
status = "A";
while(true){
   if(status == "C"){
       casper.then(function(){
           status = "stop";  // the value status is stop  in second loop
       });
   }else{
       casper.then(function(){
           status = "C";  // modify status value in first loop
       });
   }
   if(status == "stop"){
       console.log("stop");
       break; // the loop should  break in second loop
   }
   console.log("run");
}
casper.run(function () {
    this.exit();
});
```

}

and Output of above should be.

```
  C
  run
  stop
```

But the program falls into an infinite loop in fact . the output is just run.
how do I do so that casper.then can execute in sync after next statement?
I'm doing this just to use casper in the state machine. casper.then is required to modify the value of global variables.But now I am puzzeled by above problem.

Comment: You have to use casper.then, here's an example of a loop in casperjs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964704/casperjs-phantomjs-then-in-do-while-loop-doesnt-work/41975513#41975513

Comment: Thanks, dashmelch